# Array of union type errors using includes

Tags: typescript

Given the following:

```
type Arr = (0|1)[]
const arr: Arr = [0, 1]
const someNumber: number = 5;
arr.includes(someNumber);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type '0 | 1'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKAKADAHwIwEoDaAugFADGA9gHYDOwUAhggFywLJT7oA0U2JFNOtXIBbCADkAriIBGEOC0rS5iFAFYA3MUZwAdAEtKpADaSAJhGqphYqbPm4NQA)

Is there a way to make `arr.includes(someNumber)` work for TypeScript without changing the definition of `Arr` or doing some type casting?

Doesn't this error defeat the purpose of using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

Comment: Are you looking for .filter?

Comment: @Vega, I'm not, thanks! I'm looking for "a way to make arr.includes(someNumber) work for TypeScript without changing the definition of `Arr` or doing some type casting?" as stated on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't this error defeat the purpose of using Array.prototype.includes()?

Not really. It's just TypeScript doing its job: making the code typesafe. You've said that `arr` can **only** include the values `0` or `1`, so calling `includes` with a value that **can't** be in the array is a type error. (That said, I could definitely see an argument for `includes` to accept `number` instead of `0 | 1` in a case like that. I suspect there are counter-arguments though.)

You could write a utility function to check if a `number` is a valid element for `arr`:

```typescript
const isValidArrElement = (value: number): value is Arr[number] => {
    return value === 0 || value === 1;
};
```

Then use that before using `includes`:

```typescript
const arr: Arr = [0, 1]
const someNumber: number = 5;
if (isValidArrElement(someNumber) && arr.includes(someNumber)) {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKAKADAHwIwEoDaAugFADGA9gHYDOwUAltQGoCGANvQCbxwCibEALYRKdFKgBu7AK4QAXFErTBAIwhxcCqW1kNqsBPiWr1hZAD4oAb2JQ7UOBGDS4lKNt1IvUdFEyZ3GWgvFGwAbmIAXwiyKlooFgQFHmQofHQAGihsEgoaOmpyYQA5ZTU4BWNy1IBWCPoAMzRGVg5uBH4hEWBUQpKy9VwoADJhhIQAOnpKUh1OCGpeoohSkw0hm3soAHptqAmDqOIgA)

But I usually prefer to approach this the other way so that I'm not writing the `0` and `1` in two places and creating a maintenance hazard:

```typescript
const validArrElements = [0, 1] as const;
type ArrElement = (typeof validArrElements)[number];
//   ^? -- type is 0 | 1

const isValidArrElement = (value: number): value is ArrElement => {
    return (validArrElements as readonly number[]).includes(value);
};
```

Note that `isValidArrElement` **does** have a type assertion in it. I'm not bothered about that, because I only do this in these pairs of things (constant arrays of valid values and type checkers for them).

The usage is the same as above:

```typescript
const arr: Arr = [0, 1]
const someNumber: number = 5;
if (isValidArrElement(someNumber) && arr.includes(someNumber)) {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYEsAmBBATlgokgUwFsCwoIYBeGAbQAYAaGARgF0YELRIoBuAKCgBPAA4EY2PIRJkqMABTCxIAGbxk6SfmKlyAShpgArkQBGBLKwEB6azHsA9APz9Bo8ZLlbpumldfc0DAoEABqGpg42jKw1PKISEYEAFwwxmYWeqkJScEU3jqylAB8MADe-Pb2WARQRlhgCgmaUT5kFJwwNQho4EhCaSbmWH56AHQoYMCJaAQQ8chJegIAvgL8gbAIOKme1PRMbBvgQRAgJAByQxap6cNyAKwCKGryIeGokVKFUPJnl9csHoYAAyEEcHATKYzOZ-c4EK4ZIHAipVGC2GBjLH8Fb8IA)

Answer (score 1):

You defined a union type consisting of `0 | 1` which means your array values will be type-guarded with value `0` or `1`. That's how [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) work in Typescript.

The usual array will be defined with a primitive type like below

```
const arr: Array<number> = [0, 1]
```

That is one of choices

But if you still want to go with your union type definition, you can cast it to `number[]` which allows all numbers being used in array's functions

```
type Arr = (0|1)[]
const arr: Arr = [0, 1]
const someNumber: number = 5;
(arr as readonly number[]).includes(someNumber) //correct

const someString: string = "5";
(arr as readonly number[]).includes(someString) //error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKAKADAHwIwEoDaAugFADGA9gHYDOwUAhggFywLJT7oA0U2JFNOtXIBbCADkAriIBGEOC0rS5iFAFYA3MVSNE9alDgR6AEyoAbEFCWz5RXADoAlpVLnJJiNVTCxU23C4xGRUtFC%20EADKwHAuAOYstLGUcewARGppWjps%20obGZpSW1sp2hI4ubh5ePqJRMfG4QA)

Comment: Thanks! I know I can solve this by changing the definition of `arr` or doing type casting, that's why I asked: "Is there a way to make `arr.includes(someNumber)` work for TypeScript **without changing the definition of `Arr` or doing some type casting**?"

Comment: Oh, perhaps I missed that part due to wording. By the way, I think you cannot achieve it without typecasting, and it's temporary on that condition only. After that condition, `arr` is still `arr` and nothing changes. @MauricioRobayo

Answer (score -1):

```
let scores : (string | number)[];
scores = ['Programming', 5, 'Software Design', 4]; 
const someNumber: number = 5
console.log('scores.includes(someNumber)', scores.includes(someNumber))
```

It's returing True

Comment: Thanks! but this is changing the definition of `arr`, doesn't answer my question at all: "Is there a way to make `arr.includes(someNumber)` work for TypeScript **without changing the definition of `Arr`** or doing some type casting?"